# Taking address of temporary SDL_Rect

Tags: c++, pointers, sdl

I am trying to make a simpl*er* container for text in SDL by way of classes. The class is supposed to contain a pointer to an SDL_Texture and an SDL_Rect as well as some methods to get the information from the instances of the class. My problem arises when I try to blit the texture to the screen with the following function:

```
//Assume that renderer is already created
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture.getTexture(), NULL, &texture.getRect());
```

The compiler brings my attention to the fourth parameter and states the following:

```
error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]
```

The code for my class is:

```
//Class
class Texture
{
    private:
        SDL_Texture* texture;
        SDL_Rect        rect;
    public:
        Texture(){/*Don't call any of the functions when initialized like this*/}
        Texture(SDL_Texture* texure)
        {
            this->texture = texture;
        }
        SDL_Texture* getTexture()
        {
            return texture;
        }
        SDL_Rect getRect()
        {
            return rect;
        }
        void setRect(int posX, int posY, int scale, SDL_Texture* texture)
        {
            int textW = 0;
            int textH = 0;
            SDL_QueryTexture(texture, NULL, NULL, &textW, &textH);
            this->rect = {posX,posY,textW*scale, textH*scale};
        }
};
```

The code for my main program is:

```
//Main Program
TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("./PKMNRSEU.FON", 17);
SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

Texture texture(renderText(font, "Hello", white, renderer));
texture.setRect(100, 100, 5, texture.getTexture());

bool running = true;

Uint32 startingTick;
SDL_Event event;

while (running)
{
    startingTick = SDL_GetTicks();
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            running = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture.getTexture(), NULL, &texture.getRect());
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    clockTick(startingTick);
}
SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);

TTF_CloseFont(font);
```

I have also tried instantiating my object like this:

```
Texture* texture = new Texture(renderText(font, "Hello", white, renderer));
```

But I still get the same error. I suspect it is to do with the SDL_Rect not being a pointer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's to do with `texture.getRect()` returning a temporary `SDL_Rect`.  As the last parameter is the destination it's going to throw away the result as it will update the temporary.

Comment: @Richard Critten How then do you suggest I structure getRect?

Comment: You're in wayyyy too deep. Do something simple first: `int f(); int g(int*); int main() { g(&f()); }` Understand that code and why it doesn't work.

Comment: @KerrekSB Okay will do, didn't realize this was such a complicated matter.

Comment: @TheCrifix: It's a complex language, and it's best if you get *very* comfortable with each aspect of it in isolation first, rather than trying to debug a whole complete thing where half the vocabulary is foreign to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution could be to change the signature/implementation of `getRect` as follows:

```
    SDL_Rect *getRect()
    {
        return &rect;
    }
```

Then you can call `SDL_RenderCopy` like this:

```
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture.getTexture(), NULL, texture.getRect());
```

Comment: Or return a `const` reference.